# Java thread does not change static value

Tags: java, multithreading, class

I have implemented the following code Class:

```
public class sumThread implements Runnable {
    private int index;

    private static int sum = 0;

    public sumThread(int index) {
        this.index = index;
    }

    public static int getSum() {
        return sum;
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        for (int i = 0; i < index + 100; i++) {
            sum += i;
        }
    }
}
```

Class 2:

```
import java.util.concurrent.ExecutorService;
import java.util.concurrent.Executors;

public class SigRuntime {

    public static void main(String args[]) {
        ExecutorService es = Executors.newCachedThreadPool();
        int index = 0;
        // for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
        sumThread t = new sumThread(index);
        index += 100;
        es.execute(t);
        // }
        System.out.println(sumThread.getSum());
    }}
```

I am trying to make a summation from 0 to 100 using 10 threads as each one takes a 100 values

When ever I use sumThread.getSum() I keep getting 0 as a returned value!
What's wrong with it?

Comment: Please stick to naming conventions. Class names *PascalCase*.

Comment: You are sure es.execute(t); work? From my knowledge you can start a thread with .start();

Comment: @Athl1n3 Note that your `sum` variable is a shared variable that is changed by all threads, it should be `volatile`. Also note that `+=` is **not** an **atomic** operation. Which means you will lose some of the increments since you don't protect it. Use an `AtomicInteger` or synchronize the increment.

Comment: es is initializing as follows ExecutorService es = Executors.newCachedThreadPool(); this method can be found in book, Java How to Program, Harvey Deitel chapter 23

Comment: @Zabuza I've tried executing 1 thread only, but it still gives 0

Comment: @Athl1n3 Show the full code, create a [mcve] (emphasis on **complete**). I'm sure it has to do with the two things I just mentioned (or you forgot to start the threads).

Comment: I am curious why you want that variable to be static.

Comment: @raul1ro I want the summation of the whole result of threads, first thread sums 0-99, 2nd100-199, 200-299...

Comment: @Zabuza edited the topic, full code added

Comment: What do you think `es.execute(t)` does? And why do you think so? [Javadoc](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/Executor.html#execute-java.lang.Runnable-) says: *Executes the given command at **some time in the future**.* --- When you then immediately call `System.out.println(sumThread.getSum());`, the `run()` method hasn't even been invoked yet.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

the `sumThread.getSum();` method is being executed before thread initialization

if you add

```
@Override
    public void run() {
        for (int i = 0; i < index + 100; i++) {
            sum += i;
        }
        System.out.println(sumThread.getSum()); //check the sum
    }
```

you will be able to see the sum result.

when you create a thread the application continue the linear execution and then execute the thread when the random algorithm decides.

Comment: God, I don't believe I missed that! looks like time to sleep

Comment: Is there a possible wait to make the program wait till the whole thread executes using ExecutorService?

Comment: P.S: found it, you can use es.awaitTermination(1, TimeUnit.MINUTES) so it will give all threads a minute to terminate

Comment: after had created a thread the application will continue very fast, you could stop it for a moment using  `Thread.sleep` or create other thread, put the print there and taking into consideration that the variable must be volatile.

Comment: You've not addressed the problems of visibility or atomicity here: there is no guarantee that threads will see the most recent value of `sum`, nor that the threads will not interfere when updating `sum` (since `+=` is two separate operations). The easiest fix to both is to make `sum` an `AtomicInteger` instead.